# Create a tree node when serializing data

Tags: c#, serialization, deserialization, jsonserializer

I have some data queried from a SQL database and I use this code to serialize them:

```
List<Dictionary<string, object>> rows = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
...

SqlDataAdapter adapt = new SqlDataAdapter();
adapt.Fill(dt);

Dictionary<string, object> row;
foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
    row = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
    {
        row.Add(col.ColumnName, dr[col]);
    }
    rows.Add(row);
}
return JsonSerializer.Serialize(rows);
```

It gave me this result when I serialize them:

```
{
    "operator": "Unknown",
    "extrainfo": "potential client",
    "Name": "John Doe",
    "ID": 568910,
    "LastUpdate": "2021-07-22T00:00:00",      
    "Interested?": "Yes",
    "Does it have a valid contract?": "No",
    "Contract type": "Prepaid",
    "Client willing to pay more?": "Yes, up to 20%",       
    "Comments": {}
}
```

I want all data that comes after `lastUpdate` column to be serialized inside another node, which is simply called `interview`.
Here is how I want to serialize them:

```
{
    "operator": "Unknown",
    "extrainfo": "potential client",
    "Name": "John Doe",
    "ID": 568910,
    "LastUpdate": "2021-07-22T00:00:00",          
    "interview": [
        {
            "question" : "Interested?",
            "answer": "Yes"
        },
        {
            "question" : "Does it have a valid contract?",
            "answer": "No"
        },
        {
            "question" : "Contract type",
            "answer": "Prepaid"
        },
        {
            "question" : "Client willing to pay more?",
            "answer": "Yes, up to 20%"
        },           
        {
            "question" : "Comments",
            "answer": ""
        }
    ]
}
```

Here it's how a database row looks like:
[image]

I want some help on how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> All data that comes after `lastUpdate` column to be serialized inside another node

**After** is relative:

- Your `DataTable` might define the columns in a different order then they should present in the json
- Serializer might use different ordering then your database schema

#### Filtering

I would suggest an approach where you list those fields that should be serialized as properties and treat the rest of them as `interview` question-answer pairs.

```
var propertyFields = new[] { "operator", "extrainfo", "Name", "ID", "LastUpdate" };
```

#### Capturing data

In order to create the required output (for `interview`) you might need to introduce a `class` or a `struct`. <s>I've introduced a [named ValueTuple](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-tuples) to avoid creating such. But depending on your runtime environment it may or may not available.</s> UPDATE: [ValueTuples are not supported by System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/1519#issuecomment-572751931)

```
struct Interview
{
    [JsonPropertyName("question")]
    public string Question { get; set; }
    [JsonPropertyName("answer")]
    public string Answer { get; set; }
}
```

#### Wire up

Let's put all this things together

```
static readonly string[] propertyFields = new[] { "operator", "extrainfo", "Name", "ID", "LastUpdate" };

...
Dictionary<string, object> row;
foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
    row = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    var interview = new List<Interview>();

    foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
    {
        string name = col.ColumnName;
        object value = dr[col];
        if (propertyFields.Contains(col.ColumnName))
            row.Add(name, value);
        else
            interview.Add(new Interview { Question = name, Answer = value.ToString() });

    }
    row.Add("interview", interview);
    rows.Add(row);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I used to find a solution by myself but your code works better and is more stable.

Answer (score 1):

@admiri Please look serialisation example in this link
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to?pivots=dotnet-5-0

Comment: a "link only answer" should neither be posted nor upvoted. The link can die rendering this answer useless! It is advisable to copy the important parts from the link into the answer and structure it accordingly to provide a viable solution to the problem. This would outlive the link

Comment: please edit your post, other wise sooner or later it will be flagged :)

Answer (score 1):

I substituted a list of tuples for the sql data. For the purposes of the algorithm it's going to be the same.

Note that the simplest way to do this, is to create a POCO class to hold the actual values with the nested "inteview" POCO. If this is coming from SQL then you should know the column structure.

Giving your question, I'm going to make the assumption that for whatever reason that isn't possible and you don't know the column structure ahead of time and you're doing this on the fly.

In that case you're best bet is to not use any POCO classes - including the dictionary you're currently using - and simply write out the data as JSON. One way to do that is as follows:

```
    static List<(string name, string[] values)> Data = new()
    {
        ("operator", new[] { "Unknown" } ),
        ("extrainfo", new[] { "potential client" }),
        ("Name", new[] { "John Doe" }),
        ("ID", new[] { "568910" }),
        ("LastUpdate", new[] { "2021-07-22T00:00:00" }),
        ("Interested?", new[] { "Yes" } ),
        ("Does it have a valid contract?", new[] { "No" } ),
        ("Contract type", new[] { "Prepaid" } ),
        ("Client willing to pay more?", new[] { "Yes, up to 20%" } ),
        ("Comments", new string[] { }),
    };

    static string Serilize(List<(string name, string[] values)> data)
    {
        using var output = new MemoryStream();
        using (var writer = new Utf8JsonWriter(output, new JsonWriterOptions() { Indented = true }))
        {
            bool foundQA = false;

            writer.WriteStartObject();

            foreach (var row in data)
            {
                if (!foundQA)
                {
                    foreach (var value in row.values)
                    {
                        writer.WritePropertyName(row.name);

                        if (null != value)
                            writer.WriteStringValue(value);
                        else
                            writer.WriteStringValue("");
                    }

                    if (row.name == "LastUpdate")
                    {
                        writer.WritePropertyName("interview");
                        writer.WriteStartArray();
                        foundQA = true;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    writer.WriteStartObject();

                    writer.WritePropertyName("question");
                    writer.WriteStringValue(row.name);

                    writer.WritePropertyName("answer");
                    writer.WriteStringValue(row.values.Length > 0 ? row.values[0] : "");

                    writer.WriteEndObject();
                }
            }

            if (foundQA)
            {
                writer.WriteEndArray();
            }

            writer.WriteEndObject();
        }

        return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(output.ToArray());
    }


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string formattedJson = Serilize(Data);

        Console.WriteLine("Formatted output:");
        Console.WriteLine(formattedJson);
    }
```